# CSS performance: Is that Using percentages slower than Using pixel

Tags: css, web, google-web-designer

My question is as the title. Please answer me.
I am developing a website. I would rather use percentages than pixel, because it's flexible, everything keeps same ratio despite of the width of browser.

But what I concern is: **when we using percentages, is that the browser will make alots of calculation?** Do it compute **"1% approximate to ?px"**? If that I think the loading will be slowed down.

Please answer me. Thank you alot!

Comment: Try use `vw` (width) and `vh` (height) same different percentage, make test `font-size: 2vw;`, check: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.tmpl

Answer (score 2):

`px` is fixed. `%` is not. If you use `%` the dimensions will change everytime the window is resized. So, quite intuitively, it requires calculations. `px` do not have such calculations involved. So, in terms of performance, `%` requires more calculations than `px` while resizing.

But then, `%` has its own advantages over `px`.

Comment: Agreed. If you are rendering a lot of content - use javascript to detect on resize the final size, then use css pixels for greater performance. You can calculate the correct sizes in javascript.